# TikZ: How to position a node relatively to it's edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, positioning, tikz-node

I'm struggling to find a way to position a rectangle A above another one B (e.g., by 2cm) while vertically aligning it's right-end with the center of B.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

NS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm] (A) {A};
\node [above=2cm of A,anchor=south west,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm] (B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was putting the anchor at the wrong place as I was using the syntax: `\node […,anchor=…] (n0) [above=2cm of…] {};` changing to `\node […] (n0) [above=2cm of…,anchor=…] {};` worked.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm] (B) {B};
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, anchor=east]
     (A) at ($(B.center)+(0, 2cm)$) {A};   % 2cm between centers of nodes
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Without `calc` you can use `([yshift=2cm]B)` _(no need of `.center` that is by default in this case)_.

Answer (score 5):

This is one way for doing this, place node `A` at `(B.north)` from `anchor=south east`, then shift `A` by `2cm` upward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum width=2cm]
\node(B) [draw] {B};
\node(A) at (B.north) [draw,anchor=south east,yshift=2cm] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,luatex85}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm] (B) {B};
\node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, anchor=south east,
    yshift=-2cm]
     (A) at (B.center) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here two examples using `\usetikzlibrary{fit}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, fit={(0,0) (3,2)}, inner sep=0pt, label=center:K] (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, fit={(0,0) (4.5,2)}, inner sep=0pt, label={[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt]west:$P$}] (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```